# Is there any css code to hide this features from site homepage

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, hide

I am using the Discy Wordpress theme.

What css code could I use to hide the share button and author's name from the post loop only.

[Here is a screenshot of what I would like to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN6aI.jpg)

Comment: Please pardon me, I'm a complete beginner to wordpress and stackoverflow.

Comment: `display: none` will hide it, but we can't help you in a better way if you don't share this part of your code. It's like giving a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Rafael Tavares sorry about that.. I'm a beginner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend inspecting the elements you want to hide in your browser and add `display: none` to the class/id on those elements.

Ex. Say I want to hide the 'Your Answer' text here.
[image]

I would then add some CSS

```
h2.space {
    display:none;
}
```

Edit:

Based on your needs there are a couple options:

Edit the templates used by Wordpress to exclude these elements on the necessary pages.

or

Insert some jQuery that will hide the elements on a specific page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("home") > -1) { // What the url contains on the page you don't want these elements to display
        $( "h2.space" ).addClass( "hidden" );
   }
}
```

Of course, this solution requires jQuery and a `hidden` CSS class defined, like:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
```

Some sort of class like that may already be defined in the Wordpress theme you're using.

Fiddle for this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/p6af32td/

Comment: Thanks. I learned a new thing today... but what if i only need to hide those features from the homepage and display them on inner page ( singles page ) @scilence

Comment: @PaulKelvin Please see my update for other solutions.

Comment: @PaulKelvin if this answer helped, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: can we discuss outside stack?